# how to use column value in SAS macro do loop

Tags: sas, sas-macro, do-loops

I have a problem with SAS macro. I used do% %then loop command in proc means, but function %index  uses the column name as a simple string, not as a column name. But need to check the values in the column.

Here's the macro I wrote.

```
%let varlist = mzda mzdy vyplat odmena wage payroll SALARY INSTRUCT PAYMENT;

%macro quickndirty;
    %let it_numb = %sysfunc(countw(&varlist.));

    proc means data=CZ_DATA.TRNS_FNCP_D (keep=DB_CLIENT_ID DB_ACCOUNT PAYMENT_INSTRUCT DT_REP DB_BANK_BIC DB_CLIENT_ID)noprint nway;
        class DB_CLIENT_ID DB_ACCOUNT PAYMENT_INSTRUCT;
        output out= SALARY_P2 (keep = DB_CLIENT_ID DB_ACCOUNT PAYMENT_INSTRUCT _FREQ_ );
        where DT_REP = &report_date. 


    %do i=1 %to &it_numb.;      
        %if %index(PAYMENT_INSTRUCT, %scan(&varlist., &i.))>0 %then
            %do;
                and 1=1
            %end;
        %else %if &i. = &it_numb. %then
            %do;
                and 1=0
                    %put zase 2;
            %end;
%end;
        ;
        run;

%mend;

%quickndirty
```

data sample:

```
DB_CLIENT_ID DB_ACCOUNT PAYMENT_INSTRUCT DT_REP
79325   1387348961  SALARY 01/20    11feb2020
79322   1387355558  SALARY 02/20    11feb2020
```

will anyone advise me how to modify the code to use the values from the column?  The code is not complete because I must fix this problem first.

I used the loop instead of the following command. if someone has better solution than to loop statement, can you give me some advice? But it must be still macro. But it must still be a macro, the same code will run several times and I don't want to copy the same code again and again.

```
and (PAYMENT_INSTRUCT contains 'mzda' or
     PAYMENT_INSTRUCT contains 'mzdy' or
     PAYMENT_INSTRUCT contains 'vyplat' or
     PAYMENT_INSTRUCT contains 'odmena' or
     PAYMENT_INSTRUCT contains 'wage' or
     PAYMENT_INSTRUCT contains 'payroll' or
     PAYMENT_INSTRUCT contains 'salary')
```

Thanks

Comment: %if and %index compiles before proc means, so the value of PAYMENT_INSTRUCT can't be resolved as variable in data.

Comment: What actual SAS code are you trying to use the macro language to generate?

Comment: Im trying to create some dataset, but in where is 7x contains. I want to use something better than the repeating contains

Comment: Better in what sense?

Comment: improving programming skills and more professional code? And before using contains statement are used other functions like replace, lowcase, etc.  I deleted them for simplicity.

it is better to have only 1 code in one place rather than changing it in many places.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like for an input of

```
%let varlist = mzda mzdy vyplat ;
```

you want to generate this code:

```
PAYMENT_INSTRUCT contains "mzda" 
or PAYMENT_INSTRUCT contains "mzdy" 
or PAYMENT_INSTRUCT contains "vyplat"
```

So your macro logic should be something like:

```
%let sep=;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&varlist));
  &sep PAYMENT_INSTRUCT contains "%scan(&varlist,&i)"
  %let sep=or;
%end;
```